# Shared objects, symbols, C/C++ lib linking and loading

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

### **Background**

I am a guy who has never programmed with [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/). Never. Ages ago, I used to write code in C and C++ but that was back then. Currently, I am writing Android Apps full time exclusively in Java like a lot of others.

***Note:*** This question is not about Android but about **shared objects, linking libraries in C/C++, symbol generation** and the like. So, you don't require Android know-how to answer it.

Second, for all you folks unfamiliar with NDK, it is just a facility for "talking to" the native C/C++ libs present as shared objects on Android(which is Unix based)

---

### Problem:

Now, while trying to write a call recorder Application in Android, after going through 3 days of programming hell, I found the truth:

*There is simply no way to write a fully functional Call recorder on Android using the standard framework Java APIs unless you are ready to get your hands dirty with some JNI, NDK, C/C++, etc.*

And, that I did...since yesterday night. Getting down to the C/C++ part of the code, there is one thing that the other Apps have done to successfully record calls: Make use of the `libmedia.so`(*which is a vendor specific library found on most of the Android devices in the market to access some media functions*). If it's not found, then well...I don't understand what [this](https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib/blob/master/library/src/main/cpp/callrecfix.c) guy has done:

```
int load(JNIEnv *env, jobject this) {
    void *handleLibMedia;
    void *handleLibUtils;
    int result = -1;
    lspr func = NULL;

//    pthread_t newthread = (pthread_t) thiz;
    pthread_t newthread = (pthread_t) thiz;

    handleLibMedia = dlopen("libmedia.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handleLibMedia != NULL) {
        func = dlsym(handleLibMedia, "_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E");
        if (func != NULL) {
//            result = func(env, thiz);
            result = 0;
        }
        audioSetParameters = (lasp) func;
    } else {
        result = -1;
    }

    handleLibUtils = dlopen("libutils.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (handleLibUtils != NULL) {
        fstr = dlsym(handleLibUtils, "_ZN7android7String8C2EPKc");
        if (fstr == NULL) {
            result = -1;
        }
    } else {
        result = -1;
    }

    cmd = CM_D;

    int resultTh = pthread_create(&newthread, NULL, taskAudioSetParam, NULL);

//    dlclose(handleLibMedia);
//    dlclose(handleLibUtils);

    return result;
}
```

Going through it, I got the rough idea that it checks for a library called **libmedia.so** and if it isn't able to find it, it tries to find a function called `dlsym()`:

```
func = dlsym(handleLibMedia, "_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E");
```

You can see the **scary** string `"_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E"`
You can also find this in the VLC Player's Android App too:

https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/blob/master/android-libs/libmedia.symbols

**Questions:**

- What is the string/symbol `"_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E"`?
- What is this pthread_t?
- How do I up to speed with JNI for understanding this? or what are the bare minimums and caveats I have got to know while programming in JNI to be able to code without shooting in the foot?

Comment: Not very sure but `_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E` does not sound right. It more seems like this has been a linker resolved library naming which can be different at different compilers.

Answer (score 4):

`_ZN7android11AudioSystem13setParametersEiRKNS_7String8E` is the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for the function

```
android::AudioSystem::setParameters(int, android::String8 const&)
```

The libmedia library is apparently written in C++, and so the names of its functions are mangled.  Usually you would let the compiler deal with inserting the code to dynamically link to that library, but if you want to avoid a hard dependency on it and load it at runtime, then you will need to use the mangled names to load symbols from it.

A quick google didn't reveal any documentation for that function, but I did find some old [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/006ceacb82f62a22945c7702c4c0d78f31eb2290/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp#169).  Note however that that file is gone from the current [master branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmedia/) of that repository.

---

`pthread_t` is the type used by the POSIX threads library to hold thread IDs.  Why `newthread` is being initialized with the value of `thiz` I have no idea.  The later call to `pthread_create` overwrites that value, and the variable is never used before that other as a parameter to a commented-out call to `AutioSystem::setParameters`.

---

As for your third question, that's a very broad topic.  Not loading undocumented internal libraries would be a good piece of advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the app of 'this guy' (Victor D) and it doesn't record two-way. Only Mic is recorded during voice-call like tons of other shit-recording-apps. Selecting "Voice communication " or "Voice downlink" results in a Russian error message... There is one app that does the trick and it is ACR by NLL APPS. Unfortunately it's closed-source. But I am very curious how they do it. The latter has two low-level-libraries in it's package, namely libacr.so and libencoder.so. Libacr.so has different exported JNI-function to record calls. https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/pKO4xRfF